# How to enable a button on given time? flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a project which have a complete button:

```
 Expanded(child: ElevatedButton(
                                             onPressed: () {
                                               completeTrip(
                                                   list[index]['id']);
                                             },
                                             child: Text("Complete"),
                                             style: ElevatedButton
                                                 .styleFrom(
                                               primary: Colors.green,),
                                           ),
```

and i have a date and time in my database:

```
{
    'from_date':'16-01-2022'
    'time' :'1:15 PM'
       
    }
```

**what i want is to show that button only when the given is passed, before that this button must not be shown?**

is there anything or any way to do it?
Thanks in advance <3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Stream.periodic`

```
DateTime current = DateTime.now();

Stream timer = Stream.periodic( Duration(seconds: 1), (i){
       current = current.add(Duration(seconds: 1));
      return current;
});

timer.listen((data){
     //if it reached the given time do something on your button
});
```

and at the end call `timer.cancel;`

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't figure out if you wanted help in parsing your date and time or using some sort of timer for displaying the button.So I modified @Bunny1376 's answer for adding some things:
Use a boolean to check whether to show button or not:

```
bool showBtn = false;
```

In your initState or some other place, parse the date and time you received as a json as :

```
Map<String,String> _dateTimeJson = {
  'from_date':'16-01-2022',
  'time': '1:15 PM'
};
String _dateTimeString = _dateTimeJson['from_date'] + ' ' +_dateTimeJson['time'];
DateFormat _format = DateFormat('dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm a');
DateTime _dateTime = _format.parse(_dateTimeString);
```

Here, we have appended 'time' field with 'from_date' to form a singe dateTime String which later on is parsed as DateTime.I have used intl package for this. For more details: https://pub.dev/packages/intl

Now, add a timer that executes every second to check if current date time is more than your dateTime as:

```
    DateTime current = DateTime.now();

Stream timer = Stream.periodic( Duration(seconds: 1), (i){
       current = current.add(Duration(seconds: 1));
      return current;
});

timer.listen((data){
     if(current.isAfter(_dateTime)){
    // show button
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) { 
      setState(() {
        showBtn = true;
      });
    });
  }
});
```

The logic of the button would be:

```
    if(showBtn)...[
Expanded(child: ElevatedButton(
                                             onPressed: () {
                                               completeTrip(
                                                   list[index]['id']);
                                             },
                                             child: Text("Complete"),
                                             style: ElevatedButton
                                                 .styleFrom(
                                               primary: Colors.green,),
                                           ),
]
```